# Internal Error in Drupal 7 after posting from Windows / apache to Linux

Tags: linux, drupal, window, porting

I recently upoaded my drupal 7 site from local windows system, running on apache 2, to a linux server. the local system was having php 5.3 and server has 5.2. ONce uploaded I am not able to go to any sub pages - it shows me an Internal server error.

I was able to login to admin and sube pages using ?q=user/admin, ?q=node/1 etc
but the present url is already seo friendly - like sitename.com/aboutme, etc.

How can I overcome this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `.htaccess` file

```
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and

  # modify the following line:

  # RewriteBase /drupal

  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,

  # uncomment the following line:

  # RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7: PHP 5.2.5* or higher (5.3 recommended)

there is some things you have to do with IIS to make your url clean 
http://drupal.org/node/3854
this topic will help you...